# SSO in Development environment

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

We want to use ADFS as our federated security service for authentication and have staging and production ADFS servers.

I have knocked up a simple MVC Web app that uses the staging server with the realm set to the url my site is running under "http://localhost:55483"

When I try to access a protected resource it correctly redirects me to the ADFS server, which in turn redirects me to the IdP to login.
Both the IdP and ADFS server use scripts in their responses to auto-submit html forms, back to the ADFS server and then to my own site to pass the security token around.

The problem is when it redirects back to my site it has upgraded to HTTPS!

Is there some way to disable this upgrade to HTTPS ?

I see chrome and the other browsers all seem to add this "upgrade-insecure-requests" header to the requests so I don't know if the ADFS server is respecting that ? Or if it can be disabled on the ADFS side ?

Answer (score 1):

ADFS only runs on https.

No, you can't disable it.

That's why if you have a LB you have to pass all ADFS traffic through. You can't terminate SSL on the LB.